# vDSP equivalent for Linux

Tags: linux, fft, vdsp

I have had good experiences with Apple's vDSP primitives under OS X and iOS.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html

Now I am trying to port some code that relies on vDSP to Linux and I wonder if any equivalents are available built into one of the standard libraries.

Comment: You'll need to cherry pick from various libraries I think, e.g. FFTW, Intel IPP, OpenCV, etc, depending on what kind of routines you're using.

Answer (score 0):

While there is not presently any library that matches **vDSP**, there are several alternatives you might explore. A couple off the top of my head:

- [**OpenCV**](http://opencv.org) is an impressive collection of image processing and computer vision
  routines with a vibrant user and research community.
- [**Eigen**](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) is a **C++11** template library for linear algebra:
  matrices, vectors, numerical solvers, and related algorithms.

My personal recommendation would be **Eigen**.

Comment: I guess the reason, that there is no perfect Linux equivalent is the absence of [NEON SIMD engines](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/neon.php) in most devices. [Project Ne10](http://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/) is a suitable Android pendant though.